# How to define key argument of gather function using string concatenation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I've got a `tibble` with interaction of few factors as a column names (see example with two factors below).

```
ex <- structure(list(`Monday*FALSE` = 42.74, `Monday*TRUE` = 70.68, 
`Tuesday*TRUE` = 44.05, `Tuesday*FALSE` = 51.25, `Wednesday*TRUE` = 35.57, 
`Wednesday*FALSE` = 59.24, `Thursday*TRUE` = 85.3, `Thursday*FALSE` = 59.91, 
`Friday*TRUE` = 47.27, `Friday*FALSE` = 47.44, `Saturday*TRUE` = 62.28, 
`Saturday*FALSE` = 98.8, `Sunday*TRUE` = 57.11, `Sunday*FALSE` = 65.99), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

I want to write a function that would allow to `gather` this `tibble`, but additionally create a `key` name based on input names of factors. However, the following doesn't work as intented because `paste0` returns a string.

```
my_gather <- function(data, ...){
  vars <- enquos(...)
  data %>% 
    gather(key = paste0(!!!vars, sep = '*'), value = value, factor_key = TRUE)
}

my_gather(ex, day, cond) %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `paste0(day, cond, sep = ".")` value
  <fct>                          <dbl>
1 Monday*FALSE                    42.7
2 Monday*TRUE                     70.7
3 Tuesday*TRUE                    44.0
4 Tuesday*FALSE                   51.2
5 Wednesday*TRUE                  35.6
6 Wednesday*FALSE                 59.2
```

I have tried to replace `*` by `.` to make a valid synctatic name, then capture `paste0` into a `sym` with `!!`:

```
my_gather <- function(data, ...){
   vars <- enquos(...)
   data %>% 
     gather(key = !!sym(paste0(!!!vars, sep = '.')), value = value, factor_key = TRUE)
}
```

but it results in an error:

> Error in !vars : invalid argument type

`gather` seems to quotate the `key` and `value` arguments if neccessary, so is there any way to evaluate `paste0(...)` within `key` definition?

Comment: Could you go with the infamous `eval(parse(text = paste0(...)))` route?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work because you're double unquoting:

```
!!sym(paste0(!!!vars, sep = '.'))
```

Everything inside `!!` is evaluated normally, so if you use another unquote operator it needs to be handled by another quasiquoting function. `paste0()` does not support `!!!`.

As a general rule, it is better to do things in several steps with complex syntax like `!!`. It is more readable and there's fewer chances of making mistakes.

The second thing is that you're quoting the inputs with `enquos()`. This means they can be any complex expressions instead of column names. If you're expecting bare columns, it's better to use `ensyms(...)` instead (or just `syms(c(...))` if you prefer to take strings without any quoting).

```
my_gather <- function(data, ...){
  # ensyms() guarantees there can't be complex expressions in `...`
  vars <- ensyms(...)

  # Let's convert all symbols to strings and return a character vector
  keys <- purrr::map_chr(vars, as.character)

  # Now we can use paste() the normal way. It doesn't support `!!!`
  # but the standard way of dealing with vector inputs is the
  # `collapse` argument:
  key <- paste0(keys, collapse = '*')

  # Equivalently, but weird:
  key <- eval(expr(paste(!!!keys, sep = "*")))

  # Now the key can be unquoted:
  data %>%
    gather(key = !!key, value = value, factor_key = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, really insightful. Thanks!